# How to toggle ImageView buttons

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

I am currently having three Imageview Buttons, which calls three different functions in my android app. Instead of 3 buttons, I want to use a single button, which should call each function on each tap (Like a toggle button).  Please find my current XML structure of the three independent buttons (ImageView)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_align_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_align_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_align_center"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_align_center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_align_right"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_align_right" />
```

And here is the fucntion calling script, which is used in the main activity.

```
 img_align_left.setOnClickListener { alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START) }
    img_align_center.setOnClickListener { alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER) }
    img_align_right.setOnClickListener { alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END) }
```

Let me know if the query gives you enough information. 
Thank you!

-------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------

Based on @Kam code, I was able to solve the issue ( I use Kotlin). Here is the code.

```
    var count=0
        img_align_left.setOnClickListener {

            when (count) {
                0 -> {
                    alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START)
                }


                1 -> {
            alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER)
                }

                2 ->
            {alingnText(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END)}

            }

if(count>1)
        count=0
        else
        count++}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can have is a button and a counter for which imageView you last changed.

```
    int counter = 0;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch(counter){
                    case 0:
                    //First ImageView
                    counter++;
                    break;
                    case 1:
                    //Second ImageView
                    counter++;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    //Third ImageView 
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

So every time you click the button it will change the counter value until you reach the third imageView. Once you click it again, the button will focus on the first imageView.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Shall check with the same and revert. I am a newbie to android :)

Comment: @KamThank you.Your code helped me to resolve the issue. My solution based on your answer has been updated in my query (I am using Kotlin)